# Java thread-dump: not all active threads are printed

Tags: java, jvm, thread-dump, jstack

I'm trying to understand why some of the threads are not printed in the thread-dump (captured by `kill -3 <pid>`). There are some particular ones missing, but also I noticed that `_java_thread_list` has length of 97, while there are only 43 stacktraces printed after it.

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.7+10 mixed mode):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007fe74cc1f7f0, length=97, elements={
0x00007fe9e4193000, 0x00007fe9e4197000, 0x00007fe9e41ac000, 0x00007fe9e41ae000,
0x00007fe9e41b0800, 0x00007fe9e41b2800, 0x00007fe9e424e000, 0x00007fe9e4262000,
0x00007fe9e43de000, 0x00007fe9e49df800, 0x00007fe9e4cbc000, 0x00007fe9e4cf8800,
0x00007fe9e4d0b800, 0x00007fe9e4d15800, 0x00007fe9e4d21000, 0x00007fe9e4d2b000,
0x00007fe9e4d01000, 0x00007fe9e4d44800, 0x00007fe9e4e88800, 0x00007fe9e4e8c800,
0x00007fe9e4e8f000, 0x00007fe9e4ea0000, 0x00007fe9e5053800, 0x00007fe9e5083800,
0x00007fe9e4014800, 0x00007fe8b8001000, 0x00007fe8b8002000, 0x00007fe8b8003800,
0x00007fe8b8004800, 0x00007fe8b8005800, 0x00007fe8b8007000, 0x00007fe8b8008000,
0x00007fe8b8009000, 0x00007fe8b800b000, 0x00007fe8b800c000, 0x00007fe8b800d800,
0x00007fe8b800e800, 0x00007fe8b800f800, 0x00007fe8b8011000, 0x00007fe8b8012000,
0x00007fe8b8013800, 0x00007fe8d0002000, 0x00007fe8d0005800, 0x00007fe8380ac000,
0x00007fe8540e1000, 0x00007fe8540e3800, 0x00007fe8380f1000, 0x00007fe8e4001800,
0x00007fe8e4002800, 0x00007fe8e4004000, 0x00007fe8e4005000, 0x00007fe8e4007000,
0x00007fe8e4045000, 0x00007fe8e4046800, 0x00007fe8e4048000, 0x00007fe8e404a000,
0x00007fe8e404c000, 0x00007fe8e404d800, 0x00007fe8e404f800, 0x00007fe8e4051800,
0x00007fe8e4053000, 0x00007fe8e4055000, 0x00007fe8e4057000, 0x00007fe8d4001800,
0x00007fe83007d000, 0x00007fe8c0008800, 0x00007fe8d4002800, 0x00007fe7d4034800,
0x00007fe8d4003800, 0x00007fe7cc018000, 0x00007fe8d4005000, 0x00007fe7c403d000,
0x00007fe8d4009800, 0x00007fe7bc052000, 0x00007fe8d400a800, 0x00007fe7b4001000,
0x00007fe8d400c800, 0x00007fe78c013800, 0x00007fe8d400d800, 0x00007fe7a4272000,
0x00007fe8d400e800, 0x00007fe79404a800, 0x00007fe8d4010000, 0x00007fe8481be000,
0x00007fe8d4011000, 0x00007fe7d007d000, 0x00007fe8d4012000, 0x00007fe7ac011800,
0x00007fe8d4013000, 0x00007fe780082800, 0x00007fe8d4014800, 0x00007fe778002000,
0x00007fe8d4016000, 0x00007fe770001000, 0x00007fe8d4018000, 0x00007fe754332800,
0

... 

43 stacktraces below
```

Why that happens and how I can get all threads in the dump?

Comment: SMR info is a snapshot of thread handles. It may contain handles to exiting or already terminated threads. `kill -3` dumps all *alive* Java threads. If you want to see all Thread objects including Threads that are not running anymore - get a heap dump instead.

Comment: Also, `kill -3` does not list threads that the JVM is not aware of (e.g. threads started from native code using low-level API like `pthread_create`). If you'd like to see all native threads, use [gstack](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gstack)